# Filtering sticky posts on Wordpress archive page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type, sticky

I have an archive page of custom post types called events and I filter them via a drop-down menu using custom fields, so for example, in the drop down menu 'select location', when you click london it will show posts that are located in 'london' and so on. This is the code I use

```
// allow the url to alter the query
    // eg: http://www.website.com/events?location=melbourne
    // eg: http://www.website.com/events?location=sydney
    if( !empty($_GET['location']) )
    {
        $location = explode(',', $_GET['location']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'location',
            'value'     => $location,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }
```

I have added sticky posts to the loop and they appear sticky on the default archive page for events, but they are also showing up on filtered pages even when the filtered option doesn't apply to the sticky posts. So when I select 'Manchester', the sticky posts are showing even though they are set to London. I want to know how I can get the sticky posts to filter along with normal posts correctly but potentially, still keep them sticky when the filter options apply to them. I'm using Sticky Custom Post Types plugin and have added the following code in my functions.php so that sticky posts show up on the archive pages. Any advice on this would be an absolute life saver!

```
function wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top( $posts ) {

// apply it on the archives only
if ( is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive() ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $num_posts = count( $posts );
    $sticky_offset = 0;

    // Find the sticky posts
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_posts; $i++) {

        // Put sticky posts at the top of the posts array
        if ( in_array( $posts[$i]->ID, $sticky_posts ) ) {
            $sticky_post = $posts[$i];

            // Remove sticky from current position
            array_splice( $posts, $i, 1 );

            // Move to front, after other stickies
            array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array($sticky_post) );
            $sticky_offset++;

            // Remove post from sticky posts array
            $offset = array_search($sticky_post->ID, $sticky_posts);
            unset( $sticky_posts[$offset] );
        }
    }

    // Look for more sticky posts if needed
    if ( !empty( $sticky_posts) ) {

        $stickies = get_posts( array(
            'post__in' => $sticky_posts,
            'post_type' => $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'nopaging' => true
        ) );

        foreach ( $stickies as $sticky_post ) {
            array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 1, array( $sticky_post ) );
            $sticky_offset++;
        }
    }

}

return $posts;
}

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top' );

// Add sticky class in article title to style sticky posts differently

function cpt_sticky_class($classes) {
        if ( is_sticky() ) : 
        $classes[] = 'sticky';
        return $classes;
    endif; 
    return $classes;
            }
add_filter('post_class', 'cpt_sticky_class');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're taking the long way around on this. WordPress offers sticky posts sorted by category as a default part of its interface. Couldn't you just do a simple rig of the loop, then, to get your location effect?

Comment: You can use the paramenter `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`, with this, sticky posts appear as regular post (sorted by date, or whatever you chose), and if not, you can exclude all the sticky post with `'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to sort the issue by changing `'post_status' => 'publish',` to `'post_status' => 'pending',` Which basically stopped the sticky posts from publishing when the filtered options didn't apply to it.